# Can I record sounds of every program running separately, Windows 10

Tags: recording, windows

Is there a way I can record every source of sound separately in Windows 10? For example, I want 1 track to be Google Chrome, 1 track to be a video game, Skype as another track, etc... without them being overlapped onto 1 track?

Answer (score 1):

Virtual Audio cable (with some configuration) lets you separate channels based on digital sound source.

Note: This has not been updated in a couple years so it might not work on 10.

[Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm)